# In Chrome and Edge: How to make :target jump links to id's inside svg work?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, microsoft-edge

I have a scenario like this:

https://codepen.io/agibdk/pen/RyreQL?editors=1000

```
<nav>
 <a href="#red">Red</a>
 <a href="#blue">Blue</a>
 <a href="#green">Green</a>
 <a href="#yellow">Yellow</a>
</nav>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="656" height="2224" viewBox="0 0 656 2224">
 <g id="Artboard" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <rect id="red" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="84" fill="#BC2727"/>
  <rect id="blue" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="635" fill="#3327BC"/>
  <rect id="green" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="1169" fill="#2BBC27"/>
  <rect id="yellow" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="1757" fill="#F0E625"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

In Firefox 59 the jump links work, but not in Chrome 65 nor in Edge 16.

How do I ensure (if at all possible), that my :target jump links actually scroll the page to the correct boxes in those browsers?

Comment: You fidn't tag your question javascript nor css, what means of insurance do you want?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? Currently it works (partly) using only HTML and SVG as I have tagged.

Comment: How do you want to "ensure" this behavior? You just want some stranger like us to give you a word of God, or do you want a reliable way to tell it did happen on for your user so that you can act in case it didn't (i.e programming).

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to make some simple ground plan maps with SVG, and then some jump links for navigating to "locations" on the maps (on the same HTML page).

I guess my main question is, why it doesn't seem to work with this pure SVG/HTML approach. And if it can be made to work, how.

Then if not, the outline for a solution using JS if required.

Comment: Ah... Then yes, please [edit] your question to ask the real question, because I assumed it as working (it should according to specs and does in Firefox) and thus assumed you wanted to catch buggy browsers, which would have meant some scripting assumed.

Comment: So after trying in webkit browsers, it seems they fail to do it... Workaround might be to split your elements in mutliple `<svg>`. You might also want to open an issue on their bugtrackers.

Comment: Yes you're right, it works in Firefox 59, but not in Chrome 65...

Answer (score 0):

I have deviced a fix using JavaScript (with input from various sources):

https://codepen.io/agibdk/pen/gzrWVz

HTML:

```
<nav>
 <a href="#red" data-target="red" class="navlink">Red</a>
 <a href="#blue" data-target="blue" class="navlink">Blue</a>
 <a href="#green" data-target="green" class="navlink">Green</a>
 <a href="#yellow" data-target="yellow" class="navlink">Yellow</a>
</nav>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="656" height="2224" viewBox="0 0 656 2224" id="theSVG">
 <g id="Artboard" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <rect id="red" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="84" fill="#BC2727"/>
  <rect id="blue" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="635" fill="#3327BC"/>
  <rect id="green" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="1169" fill="#2BBC27"/>
  <rect id="yellow" width="363" height="340" x="150" y="1757" fill="#F0E625"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

JavaScript:

```
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navlink"); 
var target;
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
   navLinks[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     target = e.target.getAttribute('data-target');
     var svgElement = document.getElementById(target);
     var bbox = svgElement.getBBox();
     window.scrollTo(0, bbox.y);
   },false);     
}
```